# Filter Stuck in Lens Hood

Tags: filters, lens-hood

I removed the lens hood from my camera and the UV filter came off with it. 
Now they are stuck together. How can I separate them?

Comment: What particular lens? How does the hood attach to the lens? Why in the world do you even need a UV filter when using a hood?

Comment: A photo of the lens hood and stuck filter could be helpful.

Comment: It'd help to know the make and model of the lens. I don't see how this could happen with most Canon lenses.

Comment: Use a hammer.   (note to angry people w/o sense of humor: his camera  looks like a nail from here)

Answer (score 5):

There are lens filter wrenches available, such as [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0095PQPHI), but I find [a rubber band works just as well](http://365project.org/discuss/tips-n-tricks/1664/rubber-band-filter-wrench-top-tip), and always carry a few in my gadget bag. They're also handy for holding a remote shutter release cord or to keep batteries together.

BTW, don't *leave* a rubber band on the filter, as the rubber outgasses and also may liquefy with age.

Answer (score 1):

Screw the filter back into "something else" - eg less valued adaptor ring, old lens, camera etc - not your most valuable one.

- Try varying degrees of tightening then apply a sideways force on hood and undo. You may get a combination where the hood is willing to unscrew first. You may not.
- If above fails - Screw onto "something else" as above. Take a scriber or other "sharp pointed hard thing" and press it as hard as necessary and as gently as possible into the joint between filter and something-else. ie at right angles to axis of lens so it sticks "straight out". Not hard enough to stay in position (so you'll need 3 hands) but hard enough to stop joint unscrewing.
  Now screw off lens hood.

Now the lens hood is off, throw it away or sell it on ebay or .... .
Screw on hoods are almost always aftermarket items and will often cause vignetting with zooms or when used as universal hoods on lenses they were not "designed" for.

Find a "real" hood. Maybe on ebay. Avoid ones with scriber marks.